# Numbering List of Appendices

Tags: macros, appendices, tocloft

I use the following for creating my own list of appendices (which comes as the e.g. table of figures after the toc):

```
\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{Anhangverzeichnis}
\newlistof[section]{appendices}{apc}{\listappendicesname}
\newcommand{\appendices}[1]{\addcontentsline{apc}{appendices}{#1}}
```

The list appears as it should but the list isnt numberized. The following code creates at least the first number, but gives multiple errors and no names in the list ...

```
\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{Anhangverzeichnis}
\newlistof[section]{appendices}{apc}{\listappendicesname}
\newcommand{\appendices}[1]{\refstepcounter{appendices}{\addcontentsline{apc}{appendices}{#1}}
```

Document class is article. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> The following code creates at least the first number, but gives multiple errors and no names in the list ...

Firstly, "multiple errors" arise from the fact that braces are not paired in

```
\newcommand{\appendices}[1]{\refstepcounter{appendices}{\addcontentsline{apc}{appendices}{#1}}
```

Deleting the left brace right before `\addcontentsline` solves this problem, and then no errors will be given.

Secondly, "no names in the list" is because you did not include the name (here is #1) in the definition of `\appendices`. This one and all the other minor problems are all solved in the following full example, adapted from the [doc of package `tocloft`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{Anhangverzeichnis}
\newlistof[section]{appendices}{apc}{\listappendicesname}
\newcommand{\appendices}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{appendices}%
  \par\noindent\textbf{Appendix \theappendices. #1}%
  \addcontentsline{apc}{appendices}{\theappendices\hspace{1em}#1}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofappendices

\section{title}
\appendices{abc} xxx xxx
\appendices{def} xxx xxx
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, the sec. 2.4 of doc of package `tocloft`, as well as this [blog article](https://texblog.org/2008/07/13/define-your-own-list-of/) both give a nice introduction on how to define new `toc`-like list.

Comment: Thanks! As I see in the picture of the Anhangverzeichnis, there is still no numbering before 'abc' and 'def' in form of "1" and "2" like the table of figures includes...

Comment: @Kirschbrot The content of items of `toc`-like list is the third argument of command `\addcontentsline`. I have updated the answer to add numbering.